# Most efficient way to create sequential string vector in R

Tags: r

What is the most efficient way to do this in R?

```
VIC <- c()
for(i in 1:12){
  VIC[i] <- paste0("NG.FWD.P_TFI_M",i,":HELLO")
}
```

Comment: `VIC <- paste0("NG.FWD.P_TFI_M",1:12,":HELLO")`

Answer (score 1):

Vectorizing your for loop:

```
paste0("NG.FWD.P_TFI_M",1:12,":HELLO")
```